# Locating a particular word in a text file and storing the integer after it as a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example, if a text file contains the text "Serves 4", what code can I use in order to locate where the word "Serves" occurs in the file (assume it occurs once) and store the integer right after it as a variable?

I have already parsed the file and the current variable name is:

```
def parse_file(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    name = (file.readline()).strip(' \t\n\r') #name on first line
    ingredients = [] 
    instructions = ""
    servings = 0
    line = ""
```

As of now, I reach the keyword "Serves" and the integer that follows it using this piece of code (the text files being read are consistent in their formatting, which is why it is done like this)

```
#reading serving size which is several numbers (\d+)
line = (file.readline()).strip(' \t\n\r')
servings = int((re.search("\d+", line)).group(0))
```

However, this only works if the text file I am dealing with does not have any line breaks in between the name, ingredients, and instructions sections of the text file. I need for my code to be able to handle all cases, line break or not.

This is the kind of file I am dealing with: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbumq16pgjqyr95/recipe.txt?dl=0

Comment: Please edit [your existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221730/how-do-i-find-a-particular-word-in-a-text-file-and-store-the-integer-right-after) rather than posting a new version.

Comment: _to be able to handle all cases, line break or not_ - If there are more things besides newlines between "Server" and the digits, we ll need to see an example of it.

Comment: I have added the text file example.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop over your lines and when you find `Server` in a line use `re.search()` to grub the number :

```
with open('your_file.txt','r') as f :
   for line in f :
      if 'Server' in line :
           print re.search(r'Server (\d+)',line).group(1)
```